# Java Sqlite table is created but not showing in sqlite studio

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm having an issue trying to create a table in an sqlite database i've created called ticketDB, in my program i'd like to create a table in that database and this is what the code looks like.

```
try{

    Connection c = dbConnection.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes" +
                           "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," +
                           " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL, " + 
                           " AGE            INT     NOT NULL, " + 
                           " ADDRESS        CHAR(50), " + 
                           " SALARY         REAL)"; 
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.close();
    c.close();

    }catch(Exception e2) {System.out.print(e2);}
```

dbConnection is a class that will connect to my database. When i run the code it shows that it connects to the database but does not show any errors so im assuming the database is being created but it does not show up in sqlite studio. Please help I've been researching into this for days with no results.

Comment: Maybe autocommit is disabled? Try adding `c.commit()`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are connected to the correct file?

Comment: @CL. Yeah im sure im connected to the correct file.

Comment: What path are you using in the connection string?

Comment: @CL. "jdbc:sqlite:ticketDB.sqlite" thats the path i use to access my database and i know it works because im able to connect to it and retrieve information from an existing table i created and im also able to write to it, my issue is anytime in the program i create a table it doesnt show up in my sqlite studio program.

Answer (score 0):

```
"jdbc:sqlite:ticketDB.sqlite"
```

There is no path. You are creating a new database file in some random directory.

Comment: That isnt the issue, even using this or actually putting in the correct path gives me the same result.